# Cross Domain Ajax call EasyXDM

Tags: ajax, cross-domain, easyxdm

I'm trying to make a cross domain Ajax call using EasyXDM, because this gives support for IE apparently.

I have the following code, It says in the documentation that you need to call the cors file on the other domain, but it mentions you can skip that part, I want to skip it because I can't upload the cors file there and they have allowed my domain in the headers anyway. How do I write the code without declaring the cors file?

```
var xhr = new easyXDM.Rpc();

   var response;
            function getState(){
                xhr.request({
                    url: "http://somedomain.com/misc/promo_getstate.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {
                        email: 'sofia@hotmail.com',
                      source: '1304_Spring_dly',
                      country: 'DE',
                    }
                }, function(response){
                    alert(response.status);
                   alert(response.data);
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a little late, but you might find this link helpful (it's a blog post specifically about using easyxdm to do cross-domain AJAX):

```
http://easyxdm.net/wp/2010/03/17/cross-domain-ajax/
```

Comment: there is so few people that have worked with easyXDM. May you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203172/easyxdm-download-files-from-3rd-party-service please?

Comment: That question seems to already have a correct answer, so I'm not sure what more I could add.